Как вернуть нормальное выделение кода в PyCharm 2024.1?
После обновления PyCharm до версии 2024.1 заметил, что изменилось выделение кода. Теперь при выделении в конце строк появляются вот такие курсоры:

Сответственно, если удалить выделенный фрагмент через Backspace, строки не удаляются и курсоры остаются:

Кроме того, не работает перетаскивание выделенного фрагмента в другую часть кода.
Можно ли вернуть старое поведение PyCharm при выделении кода?

Только что обновился до 2024.1, такой проблемы не наблюдаю.

Спасибо, помог сброс настроек, скорее всего, криво встало обновление.

Сочетание клавиш
alt + shift + insert
